# how to put entity associations in JSON (inside POST HTTP request) while performing CREATE operation of entity has association of another entity?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot as my backend framework and I have a `PERSON` entity which has a one-to-one relation with `GENDER` entity.
I am using `@RepositoryRestResource` for `PersonRepository` and `GenderRepository`.

The `GENDER` table is already filled with two records of MALE and FEMALE  and I have an angular form which creates a new PERSON.

In angular form, there is a list of genders with two items gotten from `GenderRepository`  (male/female). how can I put the genderId in JSON of POST Request body to create a new `Person`.

I see that most of people use text/uri-list to update existing records however I want to set it while creating not updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by giving a link to the gender entity.

**Person Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Gender gender;

    //Other columns and getter/setters are removed for brevity
}
```

**Gender Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Gender {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String gender;
}
```

The following POST request to localhost:8080/api/persons with `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`  creates a new Person entity and sets it's gender to the Gender with the id of 1.

```
{
    "name": "Mahsum",
    "surname": "Demir",
    "gender": "http://localhost:8080/api/genders/1"
}
```